# NavigableMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key out of range

Tags: java, exception, collections, dictionary

Could you explain this code snippet?

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        myMap.put("a", 50);
        myMap.put("b", 60);
        myMap.put("c", 70);

        NavigableMap<String, Integer> myMap2 = myMap.headMap("d", true);
        myMap.put("e", 90);
        myMap2.put("f", 100);//exception here
        System.out.println(myMap.size() + " " + myMap2.size());
```

output message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key out of range
    at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap.put(TreeMap.java:1407)
    at SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:13)
```

I cannot understand why I have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc on `TreeMap.headMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#headMap%28K,%20boolean%29):

> The returned map will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` on an attempt to insert a key outside its range.

Comment: What is "its range" ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Good question; the docs don't explicitly define what they mean by "range".

Comment: @gstackoverflow the range between its min and max values.

Comment: BTW the same situation may happen after adding in a NavigableSet.subset

Answer (score 3):

Read the manual:

> headMap:Returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys are strictly less than toKey.

myMap2 is a map with keys less than d. f is above d.